# How to improve the speed of MPI_scatter/MPI_gather?

Tags: mpi

I found that time used for MPI_scatter/MPI_gather continuously increased (somehow linearly) as the number of workers increases, especially when the workers are across different nodes.

I thought that MPI_scatter/MPI_gather is a parallel process, and wonder what leads to the above increasing? Is there any trick to make it faster, especially for workers distributing across CPU nodes?

Comment: What MPI implementation are you using?  What scale (number of ranks and number of nodes) is the job?  What is the interconnect between the nodes?  How much data is being moved in the scatter/gather?

Comment: Most importantly, do you also increase the size of the total data with increasing the number of workers? If so, then the bottleneck will eventually be the I/O bandwidth of the root process (probably the communication network of it's node).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root rank has to push a fixed amount of data to the other ranks. As long as all ranks reside on the same compute node, the process is limited by the memory bandwidth available. Once more nodes become involved, the network bandwidth, usually much lower than the memory bandwidth, becomes the limiting factor.

Also the time to send a message is roughly divided in two parts - initial (network setup and MPI protocol handshake) latency and then the time it takes to physically transfer the actual data bits. As the amount of data is fixed, the total physical transfer time remains the same (as long as the transport type and therefore the bandwidth stays the same) but more setup/latency overhead is being added with each new rank that data is scattered to or gathered from, therefore the linear increase in the time it takes to complete the operation.

Answer (score 1):

How an MPI_Scatter/Gather will work varies between implementations. Some MPI implementations may choose to use a series of MPI_Send as an underlying mechanism.
The parameters that may affect how MPI_Scatter works are:
1. Number of processes
2. Size of data
3. Interconnect
For example, an implementation may avoid using a broadcast for very small number of ranks sending/receiving very large data.